# Readin from /data/dalvik-cache JavaNullPointer

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, java-io

I'm trying to list all files in /data/dalvik-cache folder but i keep getting `NullPointerException`

```
List<String> dalvikFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String dir : dalvikPath) {
            File folder = new File(dir);
            File list[] = folder.listFiles();
            for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
            {
                dalvikFiles.add( list[i].getName() );
            }
        }
```

The array `dalvikPath` contains `/data/dalvik-cache`

I request `su` before trying to list and I think i have all the permissions in my manifest.

Comment: `NullPointerException`, but where and why? Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think you need to check directory is exist or not . then you can get list of files

 File folder = new File(dir);

    if(folder.exists()){
        File list[] = folder.listFiles();
            if(list.length>0{
                 for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++){
                  }


            }           

    }else{

    }
```

Comment: My App scans for dalvik-cache folders before it starts listing files.. so the paths in dalvikPath array do exists..

Comment: If you could post the stack trace,it would be better to understand

Comment: i don't have a emulator, i'm testing directly on phone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i've modified my code and now i don't have javanullpointer but i don't "find" an files in the folders...

```
List<String> dalvikFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String dir : dalvikPath) {
            log.append("Reading " + dir + "\n");
            File folder = new File(dir);
            if (folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory()){
                try{
                    File list[] = folder.listFiles();
                    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
                    {
                        dalvikFiles.add( list[i].getName().toString() );
                        log.append(list[i].getName().toString() +"\n");
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception e) {

                }
            }
            else {
                log.append("Folder " + dir + "doesn't exist.\n");
            }
```